# Docker rails setup issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

please can someone kindly help me with a docker setup issue i have been trying to debug for days now.

my containers seem to be running fine but i cannot get the database up and running when i run docker compose run app rake db:create.

i am running docker on manjaro in virtualbox

the error i am getting is:

`PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection timed out Is the server running on host "172.18.0.3" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`

below are the configurations for both docker-compose.yml and config/database.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/data

  app:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - gem_cache:/usr/local/bundle/gems
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_HOST=db
      - POSTGRES_USERNAME=postgres

volumes:
  db_data:
  gem_cache:
  redis_data:
```

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: db
  username: postgres
  password: password
  pool: 5
```

Comment: _Is_ the database server running?  If you manually run `docker-compose up -d db`, wait a minute or so, and then run that `docker-compose run` command, does it work?

Comment: `running docker on manjaro in virtualbox`, make sure you install `postgresql`. If don't install you can follow https://dev.to/lobo_tuerto/how-to-install-postgresql-in-manjaro-linux--24bj

Comment: OP is using docker. they shouldn't need to install Postgres on host.

Comment: `running docker on manjaro in virtualbox` It may not solve this problem. But, in general, I will suggest running docker on the actual OS and not on vitualbox (or that is not possible for some reason)